# ngrx-store-localstorage: encrypt/decrypt store

Tags: angular, encryption, ngrx, ngrx-store

I'm trying to encrypt store via `ngrx-store-localstorage`, in the same way as it showed in the documentation:

```js
import { ActionReducer, MetaReducer } from '@ngrx/store';
import { localStorageSync } from 'ngrx-store-localstorage';

export function _localStorageSync(reducer: ActionReducer<any>): ActionReducer<any> {
  return localStorageSync({
    keys: [{
      'user': {
        encrypt: state => btoa(state),
        decrypt: state => atob(state)
      }
    }],
    rehydrate: true,
    removeOnUndefined: true
  })(reducer);
}
```

But I got an error:

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window': The string to be decoded is not correctly encoded.

How to do it properly?

Comment: shows what is saved in localstorage

Comment: @Chris `{"alerts":[],"loading":false,"error":null}`

Comment: Well, it wasn't encoded

Comment: @Chris Oh, sorry, I thought you asked about the initial state. Encrypted is `W29iamVjdCBPYmplY3Rd`

Comment: remove local storage and try again

Comment: I don't have a laptop at hand now, I'll look tomorrow morning.

Answer (score 0):

Vladimir. According to the documentation, The keys should be in any of the following two forms:

```
 1) Array of strings that represents the state.  (or)

 2) Array of Objects with key, and value pairs where the key represents the state and the value represents the additional functions like encrypt and decrypt.
```

So try the following way:

```
import { ActionReducer, MetaReducer } from '@ngrx/store';
import { localStorageSync } from 'ngrx-store-localstorage';

export function _localStorageSync(reducer: ActionReducer<any>): ActionReducer<any> {
  return localStorageSync({
    keys: [
{
      user: {
        encrypt: state => btoa(state),
        decrypt: state => atob(state)
           }
}

],
    rehydrate: true,
    removeOnUndefined: true
  })(reducer);
}
```

NOTE: The key **user** should represent the correctly. Try to fix it.

If you have more than one key You can use like below:

```
{ .... all imports ....}
 
const SECURE_DATA =  {
  encrypt : ( state:string) => btoa(state),
  decrypt : ( state:string ) => atob(state)
}

const STORE_KEYS_TO_PERSIST = [
  { auth : SECURE_DATA },
  { users : SECURE_DATA },
 ...
];

export interface StoreState {
  auth: User;
  users: UserReducer;
 ...
}

export const reducers: ActionReducerMap<StoreState> = {
  auth: authReducer,
  users: userReducer,
  ...
};

export function localStorageSyncReducer(
  reducer: ActionReducer<StoreState>
): ActionReducer<StoreState> {
  return localStorageSync({
    keys: STORE_KEYS_TO_PERSIST,
    rehydrate: true,
  })(reducer);
}
```